# Add Icon 83.5x83.5@2x to iOS App in Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova with remote-build

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have added a icon called `icon-83.5-2x.png` in the res folder and add the following line to the config.xml:

`<icon height="167" src="res/icons/ios/icon-83.5-2x.png" width="167" />`

the icon is copied into the folder `AppIcon.appiconset` on my windows machine but not on my mac. How can I add the iPad Pro icon to the Xcode project?

Comment: you can add the same in ios platform folder , `\platforms\ios\FinXCRM\Resources\icons` with the icon name as `icon-83.5@2x`. Now try to build the project by taking the ios platform to xcode

Comment: Hi @Webruster, the image is already there with the correct file name. But when i build it with visual studio and remotebuild on my mac, the image is not copied to the max folder.

Comment: i can tel u a work around, just see if it workout for you, try to copy the ios folder in platform and open that folder directly in MAC and in that folder you will find a ` xcodeproj` with your Project name, try to open it and build over the xcode and see that you can see the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is support for this icon size in the latest version of the iOS platform support in Cordova, with Cordova v6.1.0 (iOS Platform support v4.1.0). As of March 2016, Visual Studio's Cordova tooling is using Cordova v6.0.0 (with iOS platform v.4.0). Until the Visual Studio default changes, here's how you can update your project to use Cordova 6.1 with the updated iOS platform which will fix your issue:

1. Open `config.xml` in your project
2. Go to the **Platforms** tab
3. Change the **Cordova CLI** version to "6.1.0"
4. Close the window and save your changes
5. Build the project again

Now you should see that the icon is copied via remote build correctly.

I'll also add that I'm a part of the Visual Studio Cordova tools team and in our initial testing with 6.1.0 so far we haven't found any issues. However, until we complete our full test passes, there may be some problems we just haven't encountered yet.

Comment: Tested with Cordova v6.1.1. It is now working. Thank you!